# Qt5 static build on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Hi I am trying to static build of qt5 since last month and fallow many guidelines available on internet but unable to build it statically. I also fallow the qt guide but they have not provided the solution of errors.

please provide the steps and dependency library which i have to install so that i will not get any error while building statically.

Comment: What errors are you encountering?

Comment: Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question is bad, because you're effectively just asking to do a task for you, solving an unspecified problem you encountered in your vaguely described attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Please install Qt by online installation or offline installation.

If you can run application at it created computer,but can't run at other computer.It does not matter to Qt install.

It does matter to **deploy** about QT.

Comment: I have installed it, and my project is ready to deploy but the problem is when i am making the installer by using cqtdeployer or linucdeployqt then the installer made by these application will not run on a new linux pc. there are error of libxcb-xinerma.so.0 and shareed library error. that's why i am trying to use static build of qt

Comment: I want my installer will run on maximum Linux PCs and all the dependencies will be contained in my installer

Comment: @Dipak  If you can run application at it created computer,but can't run at other computer.It does not matter to Qt.

Comment: As it is an offline installer then it should be run on another system also. my target pc is ubuntu20.04 and the application pc is also ubuntu20.04 the only difference is target pc does not have any qt dependencies installed

Comment: @Dipak Can your application run at it created computer?

Comment: @Dipak what errors are you getting exactly? But to put it short: distributing binary files on Linux is non-trivial and you might be better off with shared libs anyway.

Comment: @Whozcry Yes I am able to run my application on the pc on which it is created

Comment: @alagner is there any other way that I can make my new installer which will run on other Linux platform otherwise there is no relevance of installer

Comment: @Dipak Ok. I know where is problem.You need to package your generated application into a program for others to execute. You should learn about packaging for QT applications. This issue is unrelated to installing Qt.

Comment: I have built my qt project statically in release mode. it was built successfully. now I am trying to run the executable binary on a new pc. now getting this error  ./untitled1: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-cursor.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: when i am running the installer then getting this error ./Installeruntitled1.run: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @Dipak Do you know **deploy** about Qt? see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linux-deployment.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34645964)

Comment: @Moia I have changed my answer. I have encountered this issue before. It does matter to deploy about QT.